# How to prevent GUI (VB6) program from returning control when run from a command line?

Tags: user-interface, command-line, vb6, console, batch-file

There is a VB6 application. It can be run with command line parameters to create some report in a text file.

The problem is that when started from a batch file, application returns control immediately, so the following commands start executing. I need these following commands to wait until the VB6 app finishes its work.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command has a wait switch which does exactly what you want.

```
c:\start /w notepad
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the VB6 program as a console application.